# Change the bulk operations confirmation page

Tags: 7

How to change confirmation page in bulk operations?

Currently it is printing "You selected the following 4 items:".

I want to list titles of all items included in the bulk operation.

Comment: The items' titles are printed by default when you bulk operating on items, however, see the answer below on how to modify the list's markup so to print any field you like.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the entities are nodes, although the code can be easily adapted to any entity.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter.
 */
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'views_form_ADMIN_VIEW_MACHINE_NAME_system_1' && $form_state['step']== 'views_bulk_operations_confirm_form') {
    $items = array();
    $entity_type = 'node';
    $ids = $form_state['selection'];
    $entities = entity_load($entity_type, $ids);
    foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    $data = 'Title: '. $entity->title . '<br/>Created: <em>' . date('d/m/Y', $entity->created) . '</em>';
    $items[] = array(
    'data' => $data,
    'class' => array('item-class'),
    );
  }
    $title = '<h3>' . t('Nodes List:') . '</h3>';
    $type = 'ul';
    $attributes = array('class' => 'list-class-one list-class-two');
    $list = theme_item_list(array('items' => $items, 'title' => $title, 'type' => $type, 'attributes' => $attributes)); // Create the list.    
    $form['description']['#markup'] = $list;
  }
}
```